# ¿Cómo insertar un nuevo valor 'None' en una lista de un diccionario en Python?

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Sé que la pregunta puede parecer confusa al principio, pero haré todo lo posible para explicar lo que me gustaría aprender para mejorar mis habilidades de programación.

Digamos que tengo una ruta en la que existen 6 carpetas con las siguientes imágenes de archivo:

#### Color:

> Amarillo.png Blanco.png Rojirosado.png Turquesa.png Verde_oscuro.png Zapote.png

#### Cuerpo:

> Cuerpo_cangrejo.png

#### Fondo:

> Oceano.png

#### Ojos:

> Antenas.png Pico.png Verticales.png

#### Pinzas:

> Pinzitas.png Pinzotas.png Pinzota_pinzita.png

#### Puas:

> Arena.png Marron.png Purpura.png Verde.png

Ahora, quiero que la información anterior se almacene en un diccionario para su uso posterior, por lo que ejecuto el código a continuación **en la misma ruta en la que se encuentran las carpetas mencionadas anteriormente**:

```
import os
# Main method
the_dictionary_list = {}

for name in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        path = os.path.basename(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
```

**Entonces, después de compilar el programa anterior, obtengo mi diccionario:**

[image: Dictionary]

Pero aquí está el problema: después de crear el diccionario, ¿cómo puedo dejar que el usuario decida en qué arreglos agregar una cadena '**None**' como un nuevo valor (es decir, sin reemplazar los actuales), queriendo decir que, por ejemplo, si el usuario quisiera agregar '**None**' solo al arreglo de `Puas` y el arreglo de `Pinzas`, generaría la siguiente salida?:

```
the_dictionary_list: {
'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png','Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 
'Zapote.png'],
'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'],
'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 
'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'],
'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'],
'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

Comment: `the_dictionary_list[path].insert(0, None)`

Comment: Corrección: Python es un lenguaje interpretado.

Comment: @Christian te ha dado la respuesta, si lo que quieres insertar es un valor `None`. Si en cambio quieres insertar la cadena `'None'`, como muestras en tu ejemplo, basta que pongas comillas alrededor en la sugerencia de Christian.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creé una solución, lo que hace este código es primero preguntarle al usuario sí desea agregar el elemento `None` como valor al arreglo correspondiente de alguna llave, en caso de ser afirmativo el usuario escribirá `y` y presionará Enter, luego el programa le preguntará al usuario en cuál de las llaves validas del `the_dictionary_list` el desea agregar el elemento `None`,  el usuario sólo podrá agregar ese elemento una sola vez alguna de las llaves válidas, sí una llave ya tiene dicho elemento, informará al usuario de que dicha llave ya tienen dicho elemento y que debe escoger otra.

Este ciclo sólo se romperá cuando el usuario no quiera agregar más elementos `None` y decida escribir `n` y presionar Enter:

```
while True:

if entrada == 'y':
    key_entrada = input('Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item? Type only a valid key name:')
    while True:            
        if key_entrada in the_dictionary_list:
            if existe(key_entrada, 'None', the_dictionary_list) == False:
                the_dictionary_list[key_entrada].insert(0, 'None')
                print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list IS UPDATED:\033[0m')
                print(the_dictionary_list)
                print('\n')
                key_entrada = input('Done, do you want to add another one? (y/n):')
                if key_entrada == 'n':
                    entrada = 'n'
                    break
                if key_entrada == 'y':
                    key_entrada = input('Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item? Type only a valid key name:')
                else:
                    key_entrada = input("Invalid Input, Type 'y' or 'n' without single quotation marks:")
                    while True:
                        if key_entrada == 'n':
                            entrada = 'n'
                            break
                        if key_entrada == 'y':
                            key_entrada = input('Cool, now tell me at which key do you want me to add a "None" item? Type only a valid key name:')
                            break
                        elif key_entrada != 'n' or key_entrada != 'y':
                            key_entrada = input("Invalid Input, Type 'y' or 'n' without single quotation marks:")
                            
            if existe(key_entrada, 'None', the_dictionary_list) == True:
                key_entrada = input('That input DOES ALREADY EXIST in the dictionary, try again with another key name:') 
        
        elif entrada == 'n':
            break
        
        else:
            key_entrada = input('That input does not exist in the dictionary, try again, Type only a valid key name:')               
                               
if entrada == 'n':
    break  

elif entrada != 'y' or entrada != 'n':
    entrada = input("Invalid Input, Type 'y' or 'n' without single quotation marks:")
```

Comment: Gracias por compartirnos a todos la solución que hayaste. Pero por favor, podrías explicar como esta respuesta soluciona la duda, en lugar de tirar el código sin más?

Comment: @DanteS. Hecho.